Unable to print/use Azure Service Bus message output stored as System.Collections.Hashtable
I have a script that performs a task and, upon completion, sends a message to Azure Service Bus. I also have an Azure Function set up to monitor this queue for new messages. When a message is received, the function executes specific actions.
The message sent to the Service Bus includes two variables: filename and tenantId. However, I'm currently facing an issue where I am unable to parse, print, or utilize these variables from the received message.
The format of the message sent to the Service bus:
 $jsonMessage = @{
        "filename" = $fileName
        "tenantId" = $tenantId
    } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1

When looking at my output I see that the message is sent succesfully:
INFORMATION: message { "tenantId": "efas5-4aafs3-4as3-ebfaafsafasf1c", "filename": "202405231105.json" }

In the Azure Function waiting for the message I am trying to print it with the below code:
param([object] $mySbMsg, $TriggerMetadata)

Write-Host "PowerShell ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: $mySbMsg"
write-host $mySbMsg
write-output $mySbMsg

$mySbMsg | Format-List | Out-String | Write-Output

# If you know the property names, access them directly
Write-Output "Filename: $($mySbMsg['filename'])"
Write-Output "Tenant ID: $($mySbMsg['tenantId'])"

$filename = $mySbMsg.filename
$tenantId = $mySbMsg.tenantId

I've tried various methods to print the message, but they all result in the following:
NFORMATION: PowerShell ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: System.Collections.Hashtable
NFORMATION: System.Collections.Hashtable
OUTPUT: System.Collections.Hashtable
OUTPUT: Filename:
OUTPUT: Tenant ID:

The same thing happens when I manually try to send a message in JSON format.

How should I handle the received message in my Azure Function so I can use the output?

Have you tried converting $mySbMsg to JSON and then object. @83jahs8

@Jahnavi I appreciate the response! When converting it doesn't change anything to the output and will still show System.Collections.Hashtable.

How are you passing the input body to execute the function code. @83jahs8

I did use the code snipped from Vemlatesam from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77295154/azure-service-bus-send-message-invalid-authorization-token-signature. Only I used a different message. (the message format is shown at the top of my post)

Can you share the complete script once? @83jahs8


Unable to print/use Azure Service Bus message output stored as System.Collections.Hashtable:

The issue is with the Azure Function is receiving the message as a Hash table object but not a proper JSON object. Use below given conversions and try retrieving the filename and tenantId property.
param([object]$mySbMsg, $TriggerMetadata)

Write-Host "PowerShell ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: $mySbMsg"
$jsonmsg1 = $mySbMsg | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1
$filename = $jsonmsg1 -match '"filename": "(.*?)",'
if ($filename) {
  $filename = $matches[1]
  Write-Host "File: $filename"
} else {
  Write-Host "Error: Could not find 'filename'."
}

Output:

You can follow the same for tenant Id as well which is given below.
$jsonmsg2 = $mySbMsg | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1
$tenantId = $jsonmsg2 -match '"tenantId": "(.*?)",'
if ($tenantId) {
  $tenantId = $matches[1]
  Write-Host "Tenant: $tenantId"
} else {
  Write-Host "Error: Could not find 'tenantId'."
}

Refer matching operator -match in PowerShell for better understanding.
